# Architecture for .net application with web service

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I just need a little help how to organize my code. This is not philosophy but real problem. I am looking for a solution that works.For example in php and symfony framework it was crystal clear how to organize the code. In c# .net i feel lost.
I just want to rewrite from scratch my project reusing some parts.

**Description**
First of all as i am targeting many platforms windows mobile , windows desktop , android ,web it seems that i should expose functionality as web service instead of directly communicating with database. Is this correct ?
Then i need some client applications. A wpf one ,android and windows mobile.

In wpf i guess that i can use MVVM pattern.

**Questions**
I use postgresql  with ADO.NET and performance is amazing compared to other similar applications. I found that [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) would help a lot and was something that i was looking for. However i am having trouble where to put sql code. Ok i have model classes.. like Customer ,Oder   etc... Then where should i put the sql code ? Should i put CRUD code at separate class ? Currently i have some code in controller classes but I construct a new controller class all the time when i want to something. And this doesnt seem really good.
Is there any pattern how to organise database code ?

Comment: There are *many* patterns for how to organise database code.  The general practise would be to encapsulate functionality in a way that makes sense to the code that is consuming that functionality.  Beyond that, though, your question is probably too open-ended to solicit a concise answer.

Comment: Have a look at [Sharp Architecture](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/tree/master/NugetTemplates) for some pointers on how to manage an ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You backend part need to provide following functionallity:

1. Operate with clients: process requests from client and sends responses back to client. The main issue here is to define request/response format. You may use SOAP or REST, for example, .NET framework service frameworks (like WCF) works with both that protocols, but as for me it is more SOAP oriented. WCF uses classes set to describe service contract, so I think it is better to work with some entities instead of pure ADO.NET
2. Notify clients about errors: includes validation errors and exceptions. Validation messages needs to be displayed on the client, usually by property names, exceptions should be processed also. Also there is problem with handling database-related errors and convert it to domain model errors.
3. WCF architecture based on `services` - it is contract and its implementation accessed by set of protocols. Since WCF uses entities serialization and deserialization it is not good idea as for me to put any business logic to entity. Put it to separate classes (`repositories`) and call repositories from your services. It is so called `anemic domain model` - domain entities does not contains any business logic - in opposite to `rich domain model` - entities contains business logic.
4. Access to database is usually encapsulated to set of classes called **Data Access Layer** (Or DAL). DAL provides a set of method required for persist entities to database or load entities from database. This method should contains no business logic but encapsulates database details and structure from business logic layer. To implement that layer helper tools often used: like ORM (Entity Framework, BLToolkit etc.).
5. Business logic layer (BLL) - uses methods from DAL to persists entities. It shouldn't work with database directly - just call methods from DAL. Business logic contains all operations with entities and entity sets - including validation, calculation, permission checking and etc.

**EDIT**

To support transaction you may use decoupled from database classes like [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) or transaction support built-in to ORM.

It is always good to have business logic relatively non depended on DAL operations - i.e. business layer process entities in way it doesn't know about entities would be saved. If it is possible you may encapsulate database transactions inside DAL - but this may must you to have ugly methods with a lot of parameters and pass a lot of entities and collections to save inside transaction.

But usually it is not possible and business logic layer methods calls DAL operations few times - loads and saves additional entities. In this case transaction scopes or it ORM analogues is a good choice.

Comment: ok for example i want to place a new order. A web service placeOrder is called.Then what should be called ? BLL or Repositories ? Some business logic like database transactions where should be put ?I mean some concurrency and validation checks should be done within a transacation and this can be done only in DAL but you say no business logic there..

Comment: It should call business logic. Business logic must validate order, check amount, calculate tax etc. and save it to database using DAL.


I've edited my answer since comment can't be formatted well

Answer (score 1):

You may want to think about an N-Tier application which uses a Business logic layer, a data access layer and a user interface. More details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

I would do this, and access all my stored procedures or SQL code (or LINQ-To / EF) via the DAL (data access layer).

However, this may not be necessary if you're using web services (I guess you'll only have the UI and BL layer) - just call the web service and do what you need to do with the result.

So, your application would be UI and BL only. The BL calls the webservice (in the same way it would call the DAL if you had one), retrieves the data and does what it needs to do.

Your webservice would then be a BL and DAL only where the BL handles the request/response and communicates to the DAL to pass the data back to the application.

Answer (score 1):

> Where should I put the sql code, should I put the CRUD code in a
>   separate class?

Yes, have a look at the [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) - your data code should be separate and return objects such as `Customer`. [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) can provide suitable functionality and are industry standards.

You could also put a [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) over that, which is called from your multiple front-ends.

Make sure you use [DI](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) between your layers to reduce tight coupling, I like [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/) at the moment but there are many good frameworks.

By the way, you can also use the MVVM pattern in MVC.

Comment: is dependency injection supported in .net out of the box ?

Comment: You can use DI frameworks like Ninject, StructureMap, or Microsoft's Unity. There isn't one part of .NET itself.